# How to write to the firebase realtime database that only allows a certain UID to edit?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
{
  "rules": {
        "gallery": {
            "$artwork": {
                    ".read": "true",
                ".write": "auth.uid === \"UID\""
          }
      },
      "gallerymap": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "auth.uid === \"UID\""
      }
  }
}
```

I am creating a gallery that stores the artworks information in a real-time database, so I can add artwork through a page and store it. How do you send a write request along with the UID?

I can't find any documentation for sending a write request along with the UID.

Comment: Where is that UID stored? Is it somewhere in the DB where you specify a user as owner of an artwork or so?

Comment: @Dharmaraj It is in the database, users > **UID** > email, isAdmin, username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the `auth` variable (including `auth.uid`) you have to sign the user in to Firebase Authentication. Once a user is signed in to Firebase Authentication, their token is automatically passed with any calls to the Realtime Database SDK, and the `auth`. variable in your rules is automatically populated from that.

If you're not using Firebase Authentication yet, the simplest way to add it is by implementing [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/anonymous-auth) which doesn't require the user to enter any credentials. I usually use anonymous authentication as a first step, print the UID that I get back in my code, and then copy/paste that into my security rules.